# Find a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ in which all primes split

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Dear all, I would be grateful if someone could provide a solution to the following problem (using decomposition and inertia groups):

**Find a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ in which all primes split.**

[Hint: Use the fact that a prime splits if and only if its decomposition group is
not the full Galois group (and that the decomposition group is cyclic for
all unramified primes)]

Many thanks,
Mohammad.

Comment: Have you tried using the hint? What is it suggesting?

Comment: The answer below is wrong.$$ $$ 1) To check that $p$ splits in a number field $K = \Bbb Q[X] / (f(X))$ (where $f$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$), we have to look at the decomposition of the  polynomial $f$ modulo $p$. Your polynomial is _not_ the polynomial $f$ that is needed for this.$$ $$2) Let $K/\Bbb Q$ be a finite extension such that every rational prime splits totally. From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189986), we may assume that $K/\Bbb Q$ is Galois. Then, by Cebotarev, the density of (totally) split primes is $1/[K : \Bbb Q]$. Thus, it forces $K = \Bbb Q$.

Comment: Perhaps, @Watson, you should post an answer.

Comment: Dear @MohammadAktar, you may notice that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 13, \sqrt 17)$ is not isomorphic (as ring) to $\Bbb Q[X] / ((x^2-13)(x^2-17))$, nor to $\Bbb Q[X] / ((x^2-13)(x^2-17)(x^2-221))$ because those are not even _domains_.

Comment: Typically, a monic irreducible polynomial $f \in \Bbb Z[X]$ which has root mod $p$ (i.e. $p$ splits in the splitting field of $f$) for every $p$ must be linear (consequence of Cebotarev). Irreducibility is necessary, as $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)(x^2-6)$ shows.

Comment: @Watson actually your claim $1)$ also isn't correct (I'll write $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for simplicity): Your method only applies to those primes $p$ that are prime to the Führer $\mathcal{F} = \{ b \in \mathcal{O}_K \mid b\mathcal{O}_K \subset \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]\}$ of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$.
Of course, if $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, then everything is fine; in general, only the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to do this without using the hint. The polynomial $(x^2-13)(x^2-17)(x^2-221)$ has a root mod $p$ for all $p$; does that imply that every $p$ splits in ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{13},\sqrt{17})$? Or do I have my wires crossed?

Comment: The more I think about my answer, the less I like it. The polynomial has a root mod $5$, but $5$ is not a quadratic residue to any of the moduli $13$, $17$, or $221$. So, does $5$ split in the field?

Comment: Your answer is indeed wrong. 1) To check that $p$ splits in a number field $K = \Bbb Q[X] / (f(X))$ (where $f$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$), we have to look at the decomposition of the  polynomial $f$ modulo $p$. Your polynomial is _not_ the polynomial $f$ that is needed for this.  2) Let $K/\Bbb Q$ be a finite extension such that every rational prime splits totally. From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189986/), we may assume that $K/\Bbb Q$ is Galois. Then, by Cebotarev, it follows that the density of (totally) split primes is $1/[K : \Bbb Q]$. Thus, it forces $K = \Bbb Q$.