# Algebraic number fields in which all rational primes are inert

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ramification

Is there an algebraic number field $F\supsetneq\mathbb{Q}$ such that all rational primes are inert in $\mathcal{O}_F$?

Comment: I assume the answer is "no"; this is an attempt to answer the closed question at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1780209/1778.

Comment: if $F$ contains $\sqrt{d}$ for some $d \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0,1\}$  then it reduces to show that there is at least one prime number of the form $\pm (a+b\sqrt{d})(a-b\sqrt{d}) = \pm(a^2+ b^2 d)$ (there is [a proof there p.26](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2013/REUPapers/Sauder.pdf) ), but if $F$ contains no such square root, how to prove it ?

Comment: You should see the first answer [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15220/is-there-an-elementary-proof-of-the-infinitude-of-completely-split-primes). This holds for a general extension $L/K$, without using results like the Chebotarev density theorem. By the Kummer Dedekind theorem, if $F=\mathbb Q(\alpha)$, it is sufficient to show that the minimal polynomial $f$ of $\alpha$ has a root modulo some sufficiently large prime. This can be shown via elementary means.

Comment: A similar question for "split" is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40460

Answer (score 3):

A sledgehammer proof of the fact that there is no such number field uses Minkowski's Theorem to the effect that every number field $F\neq\mathbf Q$ is ramified over $\mathbf Q$. This means that there is at least one rational prime that ramifies in $F$. Such a prime is not inert.

Comment: this is more a comment than an answer (in my opinion)

Answer (score 3):

There are many good reasons why such a number field cannot exist, but here it is an elementary one: if $F=\mathbb Q(\alpha)$, with $\alpha$ a root of $f\in \mathbb Z[x]$ monic irreducible of degree $>1$ and $p$ is an inert prime in $F$, then $f$ is irreducible modulo $p$. However, $f(\mathbb Z)$ must be strictly bigger than $\{0,\pm1\}$ since otherwise it would be constant. Thus, there exists $n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $f(n)\neq 0,\pm1$. But then by the fundamental theorem of algebra there exists a prime number $p$ such that $p\mid f(n)$. This shows that $f$ has a root modulo $p$, hence it is not irreducible!

Comment: This isn't because of the fundamental theorem of algebra! This is because $f(n) \ne 0,\pm 1$ is an integer, so has a prime factor.